# Bounding $\delta$ without the loss of generality while proving non uniform continuity

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

To show $f(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous on an interval $I$, I show that there is an $\epsilon$ such that for **every** $\delta$ there exist $x, y \in I$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon$.

In most of these proofs I have to put some boundary on $\delta$ to get to a solution. For example - $\frac 1 x$ isn't uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$, since I can choose $\epsilon=1$ and $x=\delta, y=\frac\delta2$.

Now I have  $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac 1 \delta - \frac 2 \delta |=\frac 1 \delta $

To say this is bigger then $\epsilon$, I  should say that without the loss of generality - $0<\delta<1$.

Only then I get the desired result - $\frac 1 \delta > 1 \ge \epsilon$.

But how is it legal to bound $\delta$, if the definition is "for all $\delta$"?

Comment: Instead of deleting your old question and posting a slightly different one, you could have edited the old one.

Comment: But I gave a wrong example there...

Comment: Yes, still. That's what edits are for: correcting mistakes. I make mistakes, and I correct them by editing, because I don't want to remove all contributions (comments, answers and other) from other users. I probably would have deleted my old comment pointing out your mistake after it was corrected, especially if you asked for it.

Comment: There were no answers, only one comment pointing out a mistake I wanted to fix. That's why I allowed myself to delete it.

Comment: But okay, I get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote:

> for **every** $\delta$ there exist $x, y \in I$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon$.

This means, that you have to pick an arbitrary $\delta$ and find the pair $x,y$ (with distance among them less than $\delta$) for which the inequality holds.

You, however, picked the pairs first, saying:

> $x=\delta, y=\frac\delta2$

This naturally bounded $\delta$.

The definition tells you, that **"for every $\delta$ there is a pair..."** and yet you treat it as **"for every pair there's a $\delta$..."**.

Once again: If you manually choose some $x,y$ pair (which are, in fact, close enough, so that $|x-y|<\delta$), you lose generality. You have to *find* the fitting pair, not *choose* them. That is, what bounds $\delta$.

The correct way to go is:

1. Suppose, you have $\delta$;
2. Try, finding $\{x,y,\epsilon\}$ such that, these two conditions hold for any $\delta$:

(a) $|x-y|<\delta$;

(b) $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge\epsilon$

---

As for your example: we've got $f(x)=1/x$

I'll first eliminate $y$ by defining $y=x+\delta$. That way, $d(x,y)<\delta$ (I know, here needs to be a $\le$ sign, but it doesn't really matter. If you substitute $x+\delta$ by $x+\delta/2$, you'll see, the end result is the same).

Now, all there's left to do is find out, if there is a pair $x,\epsilon$, such that $|f(x)-f(x+\delta)|\ge\epsilon$.

$$|f(x)-f(x+\delta)|\ge\epsilon$$

$$|1/x-1/(x+\delta)|\ge\epsilon$$

$$|\frac{\delta}{x(x+\delta)}|\ge\epsilon$$

$\delta$ was known to be positive, $x$ is also positive, because we are interested in $(0,\infty)$, so we get rid of module signs:

$$\frac{\delta}{x(x+\delta)}\ge\epsilon$$

$$\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\ge x(x+\delta)$$

$$x^2+x\delta-\delta/\epsilon \le 0$$

The question reduces to: "is there a positive $\epsilon$, so that the last inequality holds?"

And actually - there is. The inequality holds if the quadratic equation $x^2+x\delta-\delta/\epsilon = 0$ has *two* solutions, that is, when its discriminant is any real nonzero number.

$$D = \delta^2 + 4 \delta/\epsilon > 0$$

$$ \delta^2 > -4\delta/\epsilon $$

$$ \delta > -4 / \epsilon $$

Actually, $\delta$ being positive, this inequality holds for *any* nonzero $\epsilon$.

---

To sum up: The question is, can we find *a single* $\epsilon > 0$, which leaves the possibility for *any* $\delta > 0$ to find $x$ (or, the pair $x,y$), holding aforesaid inequalities.

I hope, I've written everything as clearly, as it gets.

Comment: In my view, I chose an arbitrary delta and then found x,y dependent on this delta.

Comment: Is my proof wrong then? How would you do it?

Comment: I've edited the post to answer your question. Please, have a look.

Also, I dare to answer your most recent comment: "Can I choose x to be 1 and y to be 1+delta/2 or not?". No, you can not. You can not choose x and y to be, whatever you want, because the inequalities may or may not hold for the points you've chosen (and if they hold, your delta might become bounded, as we've seen). You have to find them. Or, rather, you have to find out, if such points exist for at least one nonzero epsilon.

Comment: What Whyka did seems ok to me. He chose an $\epsilon$. Then he wanted something to hold for all $\delta$, so he implicitly assumed a $\delta$ was given and chose $x$ and $y$ depending on it. It could have been worded in a more pedantic way, sure, but I see no big problem. Whyka's first comment to your answer is a good one.

Comment: Yes, guys. To that I completely agree to. However, the proof, which Whynka introduced does not guarantee to take you to the answer. The very first step was to guess, what epsilon to start with (he wrote epsilon = 1) and in this particular example, the fact, that ANY EPSILON would be just as good, eased his process. However, if one were to choose epsilon wrongly (which would easily be the case in much complicated examples), the process wouldn't give any results, until we 'guessed', what that epsilon really is.

Comment: Good thing is, we don't really need to know, what epsilon is. All we need, is to find out, if there is a possibility to find a nonzero epsilon, FOR WHICH THEN there is a possibility to find a {x,y} pair for any delta. At least, that is, what the definition tells you. Your method is acceptable for certain examples, but not for all of them.

Comment: *she. ;-)  Thanks a lot people!

Comment: You have my apologies :)

Comment: Chanto, I like the answer you gave to the original problem. It shows me a different, and more precise approach to solving this kind of problems. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: Chanto, last question- you didn't explicitly say what x is, just that is exists. Is that considered okay, formally?

Comment: By the way, I've had time to think about my answer and I think, I've missed a little detail while solving that example (f(x)=1/x). The detail was, that not only the quadratic equation must have two solutions, one of the solutions must be a positive number (since we're interested in positive x numbers only). That is, when the square root from discriminant is greater than delta. This doesn't change the overall answer, of course. Try doing it yourself and I'll edit the post, whenever I'm not dead tired. Oh, and yes: you're very welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the last comment. Yes, it's considered quite all right. The only thing we need to show, is that such x exists (thus, the formal definition of not-being uniformly continuous holds). Whether you find it or not, is optional and depends entirely on you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you could prove your statement for any $\delta$ below some bound.
That is, suppose you find some $\delta_0>0$ so that you can find $x,y\in I$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$ for any $\delta\leq\delta_0$.

You can extend this to the rest of the values of $\delta$ easily:
Suppose $\delta>\delta_0$.
Then take the pair $(x,y)$ corresponding to $\delta=\delta_0$.
Then $|x-y|<\delta_0\leq\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$ as desired.

This is why you can restrict the values of $\delta$ from above.
(But mind you that you cannot restrict them from below, since you want to show the thing for arbitrarily small $\delta$.)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: And what about the x,y? Why can't I chose them to be, for example, 1 and 1+delta/2? The definition says I can choose x,y as long as the distance between them is less then delta.

Comment: @Whyka, that is perfectly fine. You must of course choose $x$ and $y$ in a way that depends on $\delta$. (I think the other answer does not make much sense.)

Comment: In my deleted question you said I can't show the non-uniform-continuity locally for 1 (or any other specific point). What did you mean then?

Comment: @Whyka, I meant that since the function is continuous, you can only detect non-uniform continuity by looking at different points (not keeping $x$ or $y$ fixed). Now you are moving both $x$ and $y$ with $\delta$, and this is how it should go.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure I understood. Both your answers seem logical, but they seem to contradict - can I fix x or y, or not? Can I choose x to be 1 and y to be 1+delta/2 or not? By definition it seems like the answer is yes, but by the logic you gave it seems like the answer is no.

Comment: @Whyka, I might have explained things in a confusing way. When $\delta\to0$, you have to move both $x$ and $y$. When $\delta\to\infty$, you can keep them fixed. Moving the points is only necessary when dealing with arbitrarily small $\delta$. For $\delta$s above any fixed threshold you can fix the points. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how do I see this in the definition? ... for every $\delta$ there exist $x, y\in I$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ ... It seems like I should only worry about the distance between x and y, not about their position in $I$...

Comment: @Whyka, you are right. But the thing is that if you fix $x$ and move $y$ to be within $\delta$ of $x$, then you are only looking at continuity at the point $x$. This is not going to help if you want to investigate *uniform* continuity.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your patience!